# beamer, reducing table size with resizebox does not work

Tags: beamer, resize

I am trying to get a large table onto a beamer slide with the \resizebox{} command, but it is not working and I do not know why. Please help:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {charts/} }
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Regionalwahlen bis 1982}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{table}
\caption{Autonomous Community Election Results (1979-1982)} \label{tab:AC1979-82}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Autonomous Community & Political Party &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Share of the Vote (\%)} & Deputies (\%) \\  \cline{3-5}
&& Proxy (1979) & Elections (1979-82) & Difference &\\ \toprule
Andalucía&PP&4,29&17,09&12,80&15,60 \\
Andalucía&PSOE&33,58&52,71&19,13&60,55 \\
Andalucía&UCD&31,84&13,09&-18,75&13,76 \\
Cataluña&PSOE&29,79&22,58&-7,21&24,44 \\
Cataluña&UCD&12,00&10,68&-1,32&13,33 \\
Galicia&PP&14,22&30,75&16,53&36,62 \\
Galicia&PSOE&17,35&19,76&2,41&22,54 \\
Galicia&UCD&48,26&28,01&-20,25&33,80\\
Navarra&PP&0,00&16,06&16,06&18,57\\
Navarra&PSOE&21,97&19,02&-2,95&21,43\\
Navarra&UCD&33,03&26,80&6,23&28,57\\
País Vasco&PP&0,00&4,77&4,77&3,33\\
País Vasco&PSOE&19,09&14,21&-4,88&15,00\\
País Vasco&UCD&16,92&8,52&-8,40&10,00\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

(moved the table environment out of the `resizebox` because doesn't make sence to have a floating environment inside a resizebox... Left just the tabular inside)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Regionalwahlen bis 1982}
  \begin{table}
    \caption{Autonomous Community Election Results (1979-1982)} \label{tab:AC1979-82}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
Autonomous Community & Political Party &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Share of the Vote (\%)} & Deputies (\%) \\  \cline{3-5}
&& Proxy (1979) & Elections (1979-82) & Difference &\\ \toprule
Andalucía&PP&4,29&17,09&12,80&15,60 \\
Andalucía&PSOE&33,58&52,71&19,13&60,55 \\
Andalucía&UCD&31,84&13,09&-18,75&13,76 \\
Cataluña&PSOE&29,79&22,58&-7,21&24,44 \\
Cataluña&UCD&12,00&10,68&-1,32&13,33 \\
Galicia&PP&14,22&30,75&16,53&36,62 \\
Galicia&PSOE&17,35&19,76&2,41&22,54 \\
Galicia&UCD&48,26&28,01&-20,25&33,80\\
Navarra&PP&0,00&16,06&16,06&18,57\\
Navarra&PSOE&21,97&19,02&-2,95&21,43\\
Navarra&UCD&33,03&26,80&6,23&28,57\\
País Vasco&PP&0,00&4,77&4,77&3,33\\
País Vasco&PSOE&19,09&14,21&-4,88&15,00\\
País Vasco&UCD&16,92&8,52&-8,40&10,00\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 However tables are no floats in beamer

Comment: @samcarter, thanks... But I don't think the package creator did really take care about this exception (If he had... the original code would work -I suppose-). But thanks for the comment (Didn't thought about that before)

Comment: Welcome @Spaniel, semcarter's suggestions are good too (and comes from a more experienced member)... You may (at least) upvote him too and learn some things from his answer...

Answer (score 8):

- The main problem is that you only specified one column, while your table actually has six ones.
- Furthermore scaling things that contains text is not a good idea, choose an appropriate font size instead.
- `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}` is not necessary with beamer.
- I suggest to use `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline` for a better vertical spacing

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Regionalwahlen bis 1982}
%\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{table}
\caption{Autonomous Community Election Results (1979-1982)} \label{tab:AC1979-82}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\toprule
Autonomous  & Political Party &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Share of the Vote (\%)} & Deputies (\%) \\  \cmidrule{3-5}
Community& & Proxy (1979) & Elections (1979-82) & Difference &\\ \midrule
Andalucía&PP&4,29&17,09&12,80&15,60 \\
Andalucía&PSOE&33,58&52,71&19,13&60,55 \\
Andalucía&UCD&31,84&13,09&-18,75&13,76 \\
Cataluña&PSOE&29,79&22,58&-7,21&24,44 \\
Cataluña&UCD&12,00&10,68&-1,32&13,33 \\
Galicia&PP&14,22&30,75&16,53&36,62 \\
Galicia&PSOE&17,35&19,76&2,41&22,54 \\
Galicia&UCD&48,26&28,01&-20,25&33,80\\
Navarra&PP&0,00&16,06&16,06&18,57\\
Navarra&PSOE&21,97&19,02&-2,95&21,43\\
Navarra&UCD&33,03&26,80&6,23&28,57\\
País Vasco&PP&0,00&4,77&4,77&3,33\\
País Vasco&PSOE&19,09&14,21&-4,88&15,00\\
País Vasco&UCD&16,92&8,52&-8,40&10,00\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good suggestions, But I am leaving my answer too since it answers to "title's problem" (+1)

Comment: From all suggestions I gathered for this question, the addition of \tiny before the tabular instantiation was the only that worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

I would like to suggest to you some improvement in your table.

You are using `\cline` instead of `\cmidrule` and you put `\toprule` where there should be a `\midrule`.

Moreover, if you divide your headers into more lines, you need less space for the table.

I also added `siunitx` per a correct number alignment.

*Edit:* as Bernard suggested to me, instead of `\multirow...{\makecell{...}}` you could use the equivalent:

```
\multirowcell{nrow}[vmove][hor alignment]{contents}
```

where `nrow`=number of rows of the table the text should fill, `vmove`= is the (optional) vertical shift you could apply (sometimes it's needed for better alignment, in your case I set a dimension of `-7pt`), `hor alignment`= is the (optional) horizontal alignment (the default is `c`), and `contents`= text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {charts/} }
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Regionalwahlen bis 1982}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Autonomous Community Election Results (1979-1982)\label{tab:AC1979-82}} 
        \scriptsize
        \begin{tabular}{ll*{4}{S[table-format=-1.2]}}
            \toprule
            \multirowcell{2}[-7pt][l]{Autonomous\\ Community} & \multirowcell{2}[-7pt][l]{Political\\ Party} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Share of the Vote (\%)} &
            {\multirowcell{2}[-7pt]{Deputies\\ (\%)}} \\  
            \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
            & & {\makecell{Proxy\\ (1979)}} & {\makecell{Elections\\ (1979-82)}} & {Difference} &\\ 
            \midrule
            Andalucía&PP&4,29&17,09&12,80&15,60 \\
            Andalucía&PSOE&33,58&52,71&19,13&60,55 \\
            Andalucía&UCD&31,84&13,09&-18,75&13,76 \\
            Cataluña&PSOE&29,79&22,58&-7,21&24,44 \\
            Cataluña&UCD&12,00&10,68&-1,32&13,33 \\
            Galicia&PP&14,22&30,75&16,53&36,62 \\
            Galicia&PSOE&17,35&19,76&2,41&22,54 \\
            Galicia&UCD&48,26&28,01&-20,25&33,80\\
            Navarra&PP&0,00&16,06&16,06&18,57\\
            Navarra&PSOE&21,97&19,02&-2,95&21,43\\
            Navarra&UCD&33,03&26,80&6,23&28,57\\
            País Vasco&PP&0,00&4,77&4,77&3,33\\
            País Vasco&PSOE&19,09&14,21&-4,88&15,00\\
            País Vasco&UCD&16,92&8,52&-8,40&10,00\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

This is the result, I think it looks much better than with `\resizebox`:

[image]

Comment: It would be simpler to use directly `\multirowcell{2}[-7pt]{...}`.